# kendoui observable receive non enumerable properties

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Is there a way to have kendo.observable add non enumerable properties to the object it returns?  For example:

```
var someObject = {};
someObject.x = 5;
Object.defineProperty(someObject, "someString", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true
});
someObject.someString = "This is the base";

var foo = kendo.observable(someObject)

"x" in foo;  //true
"someString" in someObject;  //true
"someString" in foo;  //false, but I want this to be true
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Actually when you create new observable object out of a object that has a property which is not enumerable. The initialization actually skips to create such property.

Instead you can create observable object out of a regular object (where all properties are enumerable) and then you can change the enumerable property to be false.

Here is what I mean:

```
var bar = kendo.observable( { blabla : 123 });
Object.defineProperty(bar, 'blabla', { enumerable: false });
var isEnumerable = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(bar, 'blabla').enumerable // returns false
'blabla' in bar //returns true
```

Comment: Hmm, your comment that it skips to create such a property is interesting.  Where do you see that?  There are some reasons why I cannot do what you suggested in your code block for my particular case, but it would work in others.